# How to declare piecewise function in matlab with a double value in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I wrote a function `y` that is basiclly a piecewise function.
When I call the function with value `x(t)` that accepts double values, and then try to plot my function, I get this error:

> Error using plot
>   Data must be numeric, datetime, duration or an array convertible to double.

What am I doing wrong?

My function:

```
function y = func1(x)
syms x t
y = piecewise(x<-2, -2, -2<x<2, x, x>2, 2);
end
```

And here is how i am using this function:

```
N=1000;
t=linspace(0,10,N+1);
t(end)=[];
x1=(3*sin(2*pi*t/4)+0.5*cos(2*pi*6*t));

y= func1(x1);
figure;hold on; grid on;
plot(t,x1,'b','LineWidth',2)
plot(t,y,':r','LineWidth',2)
legend('x(t)','y(t)');
```

Comment: `func1` returns a symbolic expression. Note that you overwrite `x` inside the function.

Comment: how i overwrite x ? i can't see this ? and what does it mean func1 returns a symbolic expression ?

Comment: `syms x` creates a symbolic variable `x`. Your input variable `x` no longer exists after this. Because `y` is defined in terms of symbolic variable `x`, it is a symbolic expression. You need to substitute `x` for a numeric value to be able to convert that to `double`. Start reading here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-numbers-variables-and-expressions.html

Comment: But you don’t need to use symbolic expressions for this. Just use array indexing instead: `x(x<-2)=-2`, etc.